# Displaying user avatar next to the activity feed notification in application-only context

Tags: microsoft-teams

As stated in the [teams store validation guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/teams-store-validation-guidelines#notifications), activity feed notifications triggered by a user should display the user avatar.
[image]

To our knowledge, this is currently not possible for application-only context when looking at the [MS graph api docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) of the endpoint we are using and the [how to guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications?tabs=http#send-activity-feed-notifications-to-users)

> The activity icon is based on the context in which the request is made. If the request is made with delegated permissions, the user's photo appears as the avatar, while the Teams app icon appears as the activity icon. In an application-only context, the Teams app icon is used as the avatar, and the activity icon is omitted.

Since this was highlighted during validation of our app and we only have been granted an exception for 3 months, we appreciate any pointers on how to provide a user avatar for application-only context using `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${graphUserId}/teamwork/sendActivityNotification` since there is nothing stated in the Graph API docs. We registered an Azure enterprise app in the Azure portal and have been granted `https://graph.microsoft.com/TeamsActivity.Send` permissions to allow sending activity feed notifications via our teams app backend.

Comment: Hello Chris, there hasn't been any alternative provided by Microsoft on how to display user's profile photo as avatar in application-only context.
However for alternative solution we can fetch users profile photo using Graph API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#get-the-photo